# Bootstrap 4 table - horizontal alignment of cell contents not working

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

[image]I am using bootstrap 4 tables to create a configurable 24 x 7 hourly scheduler. I need the radio buttons in each table cell to be horizontally aligned by always giving each table cell the width it requires, but I'm struggling to get this working. Note that the problem occurs when the table exceeds the screen width and the horizontal adjuster is required.

The code highlighting this issue is as follows:

```
<div class="row form-group ml-md-2 mr-md-2">
   <div class="col-md-12">
       <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th></th>
                   <th>8am</th>
                   <th>9am</th>
                   <th>10am</th>
                   <th>11am</th>
                   <th>12pm</th>
                   <th>13pm</th>
                   <th>14pm</th>
                   <th>15pm</th>
                   <th>16pm</th>
                   <th>17pm</th>
                   <th>18pm</th>
                   <th>13pm</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td><strong>Sun</strong></td>
                   <td>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="radio">
                               <label class="control-label font-weight-bold">
                                   <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.MachineState" value="Manual" />
                                   <span asp-validation-for=@Model.MachineState></span>Manual
                               </label>
                           </div>
                           <div class="radio">
                               <label class="control-label font-weight-bold">
                                   <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.MachineState" value="On" />
                                   <span asp-validation-for=@Model.MachineState></span>On
                               </label>
                           </div>
                           <div class="radio">
                               <label class="control-label font-weight-bold">
                                   <input type="radio" asp-for="@Model.MachineState" value="Off" />
                                   <span asp-validation-for=@Model.MachineState></span>Off
                               </label>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </td>
                   ...  @*Repeat this <td></td> for the other day - time cells. *@ 

               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
</div>
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: can you please share screenshot of the issue?

Comment: The following use of the min-width styling update is a hard-coded solution to this: ``` <td style="min-width:80px;">   <div class="form-group">  <div class="radio"> ...   </div> </div> </td>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your comment said, you need to add min width to keep them horizontal.

You just need to add the following css code in style.

```
<style>
    .table td:not(:first-child) {
        min-width: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using bootsrap4, add class `form-check-inline` for radio buttons to appear on the same line. check [radio-line](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_radio_inline&stacked=h) for reference.

2) The `table` is auto sizeable, it will adjust automatically, so instead of giving auto-scroll to each cell give auto-scroll to the entire table. By using CSS below classes

```
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
```

3) check below [horizontally-scroll with radio-buttons inline](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aurf7q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for refrence.

4) but if you want to get auto-scroll for each-cell, create a class and add below CSS to each `<td>`

```
    max-width: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. See the image I have added that highlights the problem. I need the "Manual" radio button horizontally aligned, just like the "On" and "Off" radio buttons.

Comment: @TommyBoyWest, can you please add **'width:70px**  to the  **'radio'** class or increase the width till you get the **Manual** text in appearing in the same line. As I said **table** is auto-sizable, so it will set the width to each cell automatically. so to override that increase the width.

Comment: check below [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hythz2?file=src/app/app.component.html) for reference